# Random.nextBoolean() Always Returns True No Matter the Seed

Tags: java, loops, random, boolean

When I run the following code, no matter what range I use for the `for` loop, the code always prints out `true` ten times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Random bool = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bool.setSeed(i);
        System.out.println(bool.nextBoolean());
    }
}
```

However, if I make a slight change to the code and let the random generator run the `nextBoolean()` function once before printing, I get a normal distribution of `true` and `false` in the output that chages when I change the range of the for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Random bool = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bool.setSeed(i);
        bool.nextBoolean(); //Only change
        System.out.println(bool.nextBoolean());
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the `nextBoolean()` function always returns `true` when executed the first time, is there any reason for this behavior?

Comment: What do you think `setSeed` does?

Comment: There is no guarentee that simply changing the seed to the Random object will change the first boolean or the second boolean returned by nextBoolean().

Comment: Shouldn't it create a different pattern of `true` and `false` for the random generator every time?

Comment: No. A random generator is required to return the same sequence for the same seed all the time. This is one of the most important properties.

Comment: You tested 10 values out of 2^32 possible ints and claim that "nextBoolean() function always returns true". This a very strong claim for such a big amount of research done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is found in the API for the `setSeed` method:

> The implementation of setSeed by class Random happens to use only 48 bits of the given seed.

In fact the `long` you provide as the seed value is multiplied by a fixed value (defined privately in the `Random` class) and then only the least significant 48 bits are considered. Even though this multiplier is large, because your sequence of `i` values are all consecutive they all produce seed values which are numerically similar. So the first few thousand values are effectively seen as having the same value to the `nextBoolean` method, and you get the exact same *initial* boolean value. Calling `nextBoolean` again (without calling `setSeed` again) will remultiply the seed value, so you quickly move away from seeing the same pattern.

If you do call the `setSeed` method you should only need to call it once, and you should do so outside of the loop. But the `Random` class is entirely capable of choosing its own seed value, so I recommend that you do not call `setSeed` at all unless you know why you're doing it.

Comment: So what is the best way to convert the input so it recognizes it as a unique number? Should I just multiply `i` by a very big number?

Comment: @SuperNew: use `new Date().getTime() + someCustomValue` as seed. This ensures your seed is independent of the actual iteration.

Comment: Unless you really need to choose the value of the seed, just let `Random` choose its own seed. In other words, do not call `setSeed` at all, and do not provide a seed value for the `Random` constructor.

Comment: @Arkanon Right, Random does that on its own.Thougt it then always uses "0" seed. edit: There you go :) (constructur) `public Random() {this(System.currentTimeMillis()); }`

Comment: @dognose Exactly: the `Random` class is entirely capable of choosing its own seed to offer as much randomness as the average machine is capable of offering. So trying to choose a seed manually is duplication of work and likely to result in less randomness than you'd get by letting Java do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the `nextBoolean` method can only return either `true` or `false`. And total number of `seed` values can be `[Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE]`. So, you can assume that for half of these seeds you'll get `true` and for other half you'll get `false`.

Now when you iterate for 10 numbers, it might be possible that for those 10 seeds, the value you get is `true`. When you try over a considerable greater range, you're more likely to get equal distribution of both the values.

Now every time you call `nextBoolean()`, the seed is updated to some other value, by using `(seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)`. So if current seed is `1`, the next seed will be `25214903916`, where you can get `true` or `false` (which you don't know). That is why you get `false` sometimes when you call `nextBoolean()` twice in the loop. After all, it's pseudo-random number generator.

BTW, you really don't need to call `setSeed()` method. That method is just used to reset the seed to a particular value. The Random class instance will itself start with a seed value, and update it every time you get a value from it. You don't need to worry about it.

If you see the code of `Random` class, this is how they assign the seed first time:

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}

private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

So, you should leave the task to that only.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of the reason we call them "psuedorandom" numbers. There's a complicated and generally irreversible, but still deterministic, function behind every random call; usually a simple-cellular-automaton. The return of true for so many of the randomization seeds is an artifact of this function; to be certain that you're getting something arguably random, I suggest using a large and variant number, such as from System.nanoTime().